# Get spider name in scrapy feed exporter

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to access the name of the current spider in a feed exporter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The doc about [storage URI parameters](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters) might help.

Or, if you are building your own:
The methods used by exporters support passing the spider object to it.
For example:

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
   print spider.name

def close_spider(self, spider):
   print spider.name

def item_scraped(self, item, spider):
   print spider.name
```